# how to translate bash script "echo messages" automatic method

Tags: bash, i18n

I have a bash script that i need to translate to other languages. Only echo messages

Is there some **automatic method, translation whole script**, or tool that can help me translate all messages "echo" into other languages? (To avoid having to enter all the "echo" in the google translator)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/380847/is-it-possible-to-translate-words-via-terminal

Comment: that's the same as putting all the "echo" in the google translator

Comment: can you clairfy what you want / don't want?, i don't see how "dict -d fd-eng-spa "how are you?"" is the same as google translate

Comment: is the same thing as putting in the google translator "how are you" and It translated "Hola cómo estás" eng-spa. What I look for in a method to translate the whole script automatically. if possible on a single line (only messages "echo")

Comment: right, so you want to leave the script in tact as it is, but have a different language version?

Comment: only echo messages need to translate. the rest does not change. For example. if I want to get all messages "echo" simply run: grep -ri echo script.sh> echo.txt. Then put echo.txt into google translator and then replacement translated texts again. This is not the idea

Comment: no, dict can be used offline, so you can pipe echo | dict, this will output the translated version on command line, no copying to the internet.

Comment: I'd go with either Gille's message cataloge with locale, or sourcing, as Giles said, "Automatic translation is science fiction".

Comment: Nobody is spamming. They are trying to *help you*. Automatic translation is extremely limited. 90% of the time it is very, very bad. Despite this, you have two users giving you solutions and you accuse them of spamming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't change some language setting and your script's echo commands will magically be another language.

you can do one of the following:

- source a language file.
- create a bash script that converts the original bash script.
- create a function in the bash script that translates the output.

As you're not keen on the dict solution as it's too google translatey... I'll bet sourcing would be a good solution for you.

a simple example would be;

/lang/en.sh

```
FILEMISSING="That file is missing..."
```

/lang/fr.sh

```
FILEMISSING="Ce fichier est manquant..."
```

actualscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

LANGUAGE=${LANG:0:2}
source /lang/$LANGUAGE.sh

if [ ! -f "bob.txt" ]; then
  echo "$FILEMISSING"
fi
```

Comment: there are things that can be done "magically". As gettext or other projects, but they are very complicated to manage. Also, I just want to translate messages "echo"

Comment: Gettext is using Gilles's suggestion.

Comment: yes i know, but is it is easier with google translate translator with gettext

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$"…"` syntax to specify a [string that is to be translated according to the locale](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation).

The translations must be in a [message catalog file](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-message-catalog-files.html); see the bash manual for where this file is located and the Glibc manual for the format of the file.

Of course, you (or somebody else) will have to supply the translation for each string. There's no way to translate text automatically, especially short strings out of context. Automatic translation is science fiction.

Comment: It is not science fiction. This if possible, with gettext or a simple script like this (but are difficult to handle) https://jkanetwork.com/verart.php?idart=114

Comment: @acj No. The difficult part is not the plumbing (which is what `$"…"` is about, it uses `gettext` under the hood), it's translating sentences that are more complex than “hello”. You need a human for that (you can use an automated service, but only if you don't mind producing garbage half the time).