# set language bash and put variables

Tags: shell-script, locale, i18n

I'm doing a bash script that contains two languages. But I could not achieve its structure. The messages "echo" change, the rest does not change.

Example my script:

eng

```
 echo "Hello word"
 sudo blabla
 echo "Done"
```

spa

```
echo "Hola Mundo"
sudo blabla
echo "Terminado"
```

Now this is my idea:

```
function languaje(){
lan=`echo $LANG | cut -c1-2 | grep es`
  if [ "$lan" ]; then
  spa1=Hola Mundo
  spa2=Terminado
else
  eng1=Hello word
  eng2=Done
fi
}
languaje
```

So i need to create a variables into the script

```
 $eng1
 sudo blabla
 $eng2
```

Very complicated...

This example is very easy. The situation is complicated even more when it is a function

```
function dns1(){
read -p "Put your first DNS (Example: 8.8.8.8): " DNS1
DNSNEW1=`echo $DNS1 | egrep '^(([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$'`
if [ "$DNSNEW1" ]; then
find /etc/resolv.conf -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I "{}" sed -i "s:8.8.8.8:$DNSNEW1:g"  "{}"
echo "You entered correctly DNS1 $DNS1"
fi
}
dns1
```

and need to change languaje to "read -p" and "echo"

PD: I am not very familiar with the use of gettext (and I do not like the way it works)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318650/117549

Comment: but the answer is gettext is not what I want

Comment: @bdc why not? `gettext` has been designed to solve your problem, and it has a track record of achieving its goal. If it *is* complicated, then that's because the problem-space is non-trivial...

Comment: update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `gettext` is the best solution however if you really don't want to use it maybe something like this would suffice? Assuming your bash supports arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash
greeting=("Hello World" "Hola Mundo")
goodbye=("Done" "Terminado")

test "${LANG:0:2}" == "en"
eng=$?

echo ${greeting[${eng}]}
sudo blablabla
echo ${goodbye[${eng}]}
```

Comment: It seems that your solution (gettext) is better than mine. I did not want to use gettext, but if there is no other way to do it ....

Comment: The reality is that I am not very familiar with the use of gettext (and I do not like the way it works)

Comment: @bdc the above is not using `gettext` just an array with named variables and their associated strings.

Comment: ok i got it. testing....

Comment: Actually the script is much longer than the example and some messages "echo" are within functions. This does not affect ???

Comment: Could you also provide an exemple with gettext, please? This would enhance this answer (... and help me grok it ^^)

Comment: for example: function is_dns1(){
 read -p "Put your first DNS (Example: 8.8.8.8): " DNS1
 DNSNEW1=`echo $DNS1 | egrep '^(([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$'`
 if [ "$DNSNEW1" ]; then
 find folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I "{}" sed -i "s:8.8.4.4:$DNSNEW1:g"  "{}"
 echo "You entered correctly DNS1 $DNS1"
   fi
}

Comment: doesn't work with "read -p"

Comment: works read -p with quotation marks "${greeting[${eng}]}"